# ¿como puedo cambiar los estilos de un elemento padre?

Tags: html, css

¿Cómo puedo cambiar los estilos de un elemento padre?

Quiero cambiar los estilos del contenedor padre al dar el evento checked: `checkbox.alimento input[type = checkbox]:checked`

```
.alimento input[type = checkbox] {
    display: none;
}

.alimento input[type = checkbox] + label {
    font-weight: normal;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Elena, fíjate en que tienes algunos errores tipográficos ya que el `type="checkbox"` debería ir con comillas. Para detectar el evento padre deberías de poner `:checked` después de los corchetes del input. En la pregunta que te he enlazado puedes ver un ejemplo funcional con lo que pides. saludos!

Comment: @FranciscoRomero las comillas no son necesarias si no hay caracteres especiales

Answer (score 2):

Lastimosamente con solo CSS no puedes seleccionar un elemento padre, pero esto si lo puedes hacer con Javascript, un ejemplo te lo dejo a continuación:

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    ¿Eres mayor de edad?
    <input type="checkbox" name="Hola" id="" class="custom-checkbox">
  </div>

  <div class="parent">
    ¿Sabes inglés?
    <input type="checkbox" name="Hola" id="" class="custom-checkbox">
  </div>

  <script>
    let customCheckboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('custom-checkbox');
    let customStyles = `
      border: 2px solid red;
    `;
    
    for (const box of customCheckboxes) {
      box.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        let parent = event.target.parentNode;

        if (event.target.checked) {
          parent.style = customStyles;
        } else {
          parent.style = "";
        }

      });
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Aquí mediante la captura de todas las clases `custom-checkbox` obtenemos elementos específicos a los cuales queremos hacerle modificación a su contenedor ancestro (padre), a estos le añadimos el `eventListener` de `change`, si el input tiene el check activo cambia los estilos del nodo padre, gracias a `.parentNode` que es un atributo que te devuelve el nodo padre de un elemento, ya que tienes el nodo puedes aplicar las transformaciones necesarias ya sea añadiéndole una clase o modificando sus estilos directamente, como en este ejemplo.

Comment: muchas gracias me funciono